# Can not change firstDayOfWeek of calendar in qml Qt5.7.0

Tags: qt, calendar, qml

In Calendar qml doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-calendar.html#dayOfWeekFormat-prop i do not see any property to change the firstDayOfWeek. So i look into calendar.qml (source code of qt 5.7.0) and i saw a property __locale

```
/*!The locale that this calendar should use to display itself.
Affects how dates and day names are localized, as well as which
day is considered the first in a week.

To set an Australian locale, for example:

\code
locale: Qt.locale("en_AU")
\endcode

The default locale is \c Qt.locale().
*/
property var __locale: Qt.locale()
```

An object created by Qt.locale() will have a property firstDayOfWeek
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-locale.html#firstDayOfWeek-prop

I want to change the first day of week of a calendar so i set

```
Calendar {
   id: cal
   Component.onCompleted: {
       cal.__locale.firstDayOfWeek = Locale.Tuesday;
  }
}
```

But the firstDayOfWeek do not change
Can anyone tell me what did i do wrong ?
Is there any other ways to change the firstDayOfWeek of calendar in qml ?

Thank you

Comment: `__locale` expect to be assigned with a `Locale` object. That's it. You should fine the locale that matches your requirements and set that. But instead of setting it on the private property `__locale` just set it on `locale`, as the documentation you have copied here states (!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Qt 5.10, the locale property [will be public](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60217). Until then, you can assign a locale like this:

```
Calendar {
    __locale: Qt.locale("en_GB")
}
```

Comment: So there is no way to change firstDayOfWeek of a calendar to (for example)  wednesday ? Because there is no region use wednesday as the firstDayOfWeek

Comment: No, I think the locale determines that.